# Displaying time from serial when text in same cell

Tags: excel, function, serialization, text, time

I am trying to get a cell in Excel to say "Best Time: TIME" with the formula

`="Best Time: "& MIN(B3:B1003)"`

But it displays the value as a serial, `Best Time: 0.000598772148148148`. All the data used in the MIN Function is in the form mm:ss.milliseconds, e.g. `01:03.870`.

Setting the cells format to `mm:ss.000` doesn't work and none of the suggestions I have found work.

Comment: Use the `TEXT` function to format your result as a time.

Comment: When I put the formula `="Best Time: "& TEXT((MIN(B3:B1003)), MM:ss.00)` I get a `#NAME?` error, what should I put as the formula?

Comment: Your TEXT function syntax is wrong. Check HELP. And format coding should be a string.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of an answer:

```
="Best Time: "&TEXT((MIN(B3:B1003)),"[m]:ss.000")
```

Given reporting in milliseconds it seems unlikely that the minimum of one thousand readings would exceed an hour, however for the sake of a pair of brackets still safer to cover that possibility. In other words, `MM:ss.000` will display `01:03.870` for one hour, one minute and 3.87 seconds just as for one minute and 3.87 seconds.

I prefer lower case for minutes as less likely IMO to be mistaken for months.

`mm` rather than `m` if a leading `0` for single digit minutes is desired.

Answer (score 1):

Put `=min(b3:b1003)` in a cell then tap ctrl+1 and choose a custom number format of `\B\e\st Ti\m\e\: [mm]:ss.000`.

The chief benefit here is that the cell's value remains numerical.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
="Best Time: "&TEXT(MIN(B3:B1003);"[m]:ss")
```

Comment: That didn't work, but gave me idea of `="Best Time: "& TEXT((MIN(B3:B1003)), "MM:ss.000")`, which worked. Thanks for the help.